# Can we assume std::is_default_constructible<T> and std::is_constructible<T> to be equal?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Pretty short question here:

Will `std::is_default_constructible<T>` and `std::is_constructible<T>` give the same result?
And what about to the new concepts `std::default_initializable` and `std::constructible_from`.

It might be important to know the distinctions when making templated factory or emplace functions.

Comment: see possible implementation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible

Comment: In [the language specification](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tab:meta.unary.prop), `is_default_constructible<T>` is defined as have a value of `true` precisely when "`is_­constructible_­v<T>` is true."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got to reading the specification. Here's what I found:

20.15.4.3 **`is_default_constructible<T>`**:

As pointed out by @Raymon Chen in the comments: `true` precisely when `is_­constructible<T>` holds `true`.

18.4.11 **`constructible_from<T>`**:

Is defined in term of `is_constructible<T>`, but also poses the additional requirement `destructible<T>`.

18.4.12 **`default_initializable<T>`**:

Is defined in term of `constructible_from<T>`, but also requires `T{}` to be well-formed. Defining a variable of type T must be possible too; I.e. the statement `T var{};` should be well-formed.

Source: N4861 Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++